# Как запустить exe внутри msi?

Tags: visual-studio, wix, msi

Доброе время суток! Работаю над созданием msi инсталлятора с помощью wix toolkit. Понадобилось запустить exe из под msi инсталлятора. Вот мой код:

```
<Binary Id="JDK_EXE" src="..\..\jdk\jdk-6u45-windows-i586.exe"/>

<CustomAction Id="RunJavaJDKInstall"
              BinaryKey="JDK_EXE"
              ExeCommand="" 
              Return="check"/>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
 <Custom Action ="RunJavaJDKInstall" After="InstallInitialize"></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Вопрос состоит в том, что писать в ExeCommand теге, чтобы запустить на выполнение jdk-6u45-windows-i586.exe ? Предположу, что можно написать так: [SystemFolder]cmd.exe /C start jdk-6u45-windows-i586.exe, но это не работает должным образом. Прошу помочь с этим вопросом.

Comment: У вас получилось с этой задачей? Если не сложно, покажите что получилось. Спасибо.

Comment: Добрый день. Решение исходной задачи не потребовало запуск exe из под msi. Я оставил эту задачу.